# Hide classes in android aar file

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I have developed an android SDK which has to be integrated in other apps.
Now I have some backgground services and within that, I have some logic/implementations which is critical or say core of my SDK.

I read a lot of posts about proguard on here, but am not really able to know for sure whether it's possible or not.
All I was able to do is to obfuscate the code.

Basically my requirement is :
Hide my services from the developer's community to prevent it from reverse enggineered.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the SDK entirely. Then, no code of yours will exist on the client. Or, get rid of this part of the SDK, moving that code to your server, so that the code that concerns you does not exist on the client. Otherwise, by definition, if the client can execute the code, other developers can look at that code.